# Graph API - Access Token (Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I'm using Facebook PHP SDK and trying to post image to the user's wall. However I get error below:

> "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in C:\developing...\base_facebook.php on line 1033"

I understand that my access token is not valid, but I can't understand why. I have global facebook object and I'm using $facebook->api function in the subsite of my website (different url, where I have orginally asked access token). My question is that do I need new access tokens for my subsites? Basicly that would mean that I need new app key and secret code as well, because Facebook allows redirecting only for one page spesified in Developer Site.

Below is quite basic api call:

> $upload_photo = $this->facebook->api('/me/photos?access_token='.
>                   $this->facebook->getAccessToken(), 'post', $photo_details);

Comment: **Different** URL or sub-domain? Also have you tried adding the different domains to your "App Domain" field? check this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That blog post looks helpful. I'm getting my access token in "mydomain/users", but I would like to connect graph api also in "mydomain/subdomain". I tried to add different domains to App Domain, but somehow it didn't work (when I'm trying to add and pressing enter, my domain name just disappears from the field).

Comment: I noticed that I can add normal domains, but not localhost domains. Apparently there's some kind of URL checker.

Comment: this `sub.domain.com` is a sub-domain, this `domain.com/sub` is not. And both uses the same domain! If you use `domain.com` (**not** `www.domain.com`) this would work for things like `sub.domain.com` too!

Comment: oh yeah! sorry about that. I mean I'm using same domain, but I would like to connect to graph api in my subsite (for example: www.mydomain.com/example). Is it possible to use same access token or do I have to get a different one? Now I'm getting access token in site www.mydomain.com/users and somehow I can't use same access token in www.mydomain.com/example

Comment: if you are initializing the same app `$this->facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'..etc));` it should read from the session or cookie your data so `$this->facebook->getUser()` should actually return the user id!

Comment: You can use the access token anywhere you want as long as are using the same APP and Client ID as when you requested the token.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the problem is not domain-related. When you call

```
$this->facebook->getAccessToken();
```

this could give you both a user access token and an access token for the facebook application you are using. And to post on a user's wall you will need an access token for a user (or page), on behalf of which you want to publish the wall post.

If the used token is the right one, then another reason could be, that your application doesn't have the needed permissions to post a wall. You will need [extended permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for your app, like the "publish_stream" permission.

Maybe this tutorial can help you further: 
http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

It explains how to generate a FB-Login link and require extended permissions.